# ipmitool pef temperature soft shutdown

Tags: ipmi, physical-environment, ipmitool, shutdown

Recently I've had the technicians switch off the cooling system in the server room, without notifying me first.
Since the compute nodes do have IPMI cards from different manufacturers installed, I'd like to simply configure via ipmitool a threshold temperature to switch off the compute-nodes. I've found that you can set the upper critical temperature to 58 degree Celsius via

```
ipmitool <options> sensor thresh "Ambient Temp" ucr 58.000
```

but have not found how to tell it what to do, once this temperature is reached. Also, I'd like to know how to email me, or add temperature warnings to the logwatch messages, at a lower temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that setting will only result in a Critical error message and SNMP trap triggering.

Perhaps you could set up some SNMP collector that is able to run actions on trapped messages. (Ipmi poweroff, email.)

Comment: Too bad IPMI-cards don't have options cheap desktop motherboards have. While I don't like the answer, since I've hoped for a better way - it is absolutely correct and my only option - accept.